# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Skills\Validator' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**Below is my code to check the validation**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Skills;    
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'Category' => 'required|max:100|min:5'
    ]);

    if ($v->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('Skill.Category.Create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }
}
```

**This gives below error:**

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Skills\Validator' not found

Comment: Which classes you have included in this page?

Comment: Missing this import: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;`

Comment: You don't need to reference the whole path when using Facades. use Validator;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
\Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'Category' => 'required|max:100|min:5'
    ]);
```

There, is 1 more optimal solution, and that is to add: `use Validator;` on the top, of the file where other Facades and files are in use. So that you don't have to add "\" everytime you use any Facade.

See,if that works.

Comment: Validator is a Facade, and hence couldn't be called directly, if you do it will refer the namespace location and hence couldn't find Validate static class. For more info on facade you can read this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1.Prefix the class name with \ (ie. \Validator) as follow

```
$validator = \Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

2. Imports the namespaces for Validator and the another classes.

I got this information here - [Reference link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/class-apphttpcontrollersvalidator-not-found)

Answer (score -1):

Other option:

```
use Validator;
```

I wait to have help you.